# markdown to pdf and scrollbars

Tags: pdf-generation, markdown

When I use a markdown file and I use any tool to convert to pdf (pandoc, marp, etc.) wider that screen width I get something as follows:

[image: scroll bar in pdf]

The problem is the scrollbar, I'd like to get a movable scroll bar, is that possible?

Comment: PDF is made for print... working scrollbars aren't very common on paper... or what are you asking?

Comment: Yes, PDF is intended for printing, but it can be used also for presentations :)